# Some websites return a forbidden response only in Firefox on Linux (changing the user agent to Chrome works though); common cause?

Tags: linux, firefox, user-agent

In the past few years I've sometimes ran into websites that don't work in Firefox on Linux, and I'm trying to understand why so I can notify the owners with more than just a vague “it doesn't work”.

Now this happens of course. While most web developers do test in Firefox, not many will have tested their products in Firefox on Linux, and some really don't care. Some only target Chrome/Webkit and don't bother with Firefox at all. *That is not what this question is about though.*

There is something here that makes me suspect that there is an underlying cause that is repeated on seemingly unrelated websites, and I suspect some repeated bit of configuration code or web content serving library or application that does this. Something is fishy.

### The problem

The websites affected return only a plain HTML message with a 403 HTTP status code for any resource requested; it looks like this:

> ## Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

These websites **do** work when:

- The operating system is not a Linux distribution

**or**

- The browser is not Firefox

### Example websites

While I normally wouldn't include a link to someone else's website, in this case I do because it is the website of a doctors office. These websites should be available to any patient at all times for anything short of a imminently life threatening emergency (in which case the national emergency number should be called of course) to provide contact information in times of need.

This website displays the symptoms described above: https://www.huisartsenpraktijkdehaan.nl/

There are more websites though, but the pattern is always the same.

### The `user-agent` string

Trying to figure out what is actually causing this seems simple enough though. If I change the `user-agent` string to that of Chrome, it works.
So my tentative conclusion is that this is purely a user-agent driven bug/feature.

Some further testing yields this:

#### These work

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36
Foo
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; x86_64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; inux x86_64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linu x86_64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Xubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0
X11; Ubuntu; Linu
X11;Ubuntu;Linux
11; Ubuntu; Linux
```

#### These do not work

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0
X11; Ubuntu; Linux
x11; ubuntu; linux
```

### Hypothesis

Having the literal string `X11; Ubuntu; Linux` (case insensitive but including spaces and semi-colons as-is) in the `user-agent` HTTP header of your request triggers the broken behaviour.

### The conundrum

I could, of course, reach out the owners of these websites (and eventually I will), but there is a catch. They likely won't use Firefox on Linux (because you would notice your own website being broke), and if they pass on the message to whoever maintains or built the website, the response may very well be “well it works for you, and it works for me, that user must have some weird virus-ridden computer and an ancient browser with a Bonzy Buddy toolbar”, or something similar.

So I want some more ammunition, and preferably a cause I can explain to anyone with a website like this. Even better would be to find out why this happens, and fix it at the source.

So what is happening here? Some Apache of Nginx module/config/plugin written by someone who really hates people who use Firefox on Linux? Some weird bug repeated on multiple sites?

Does anyone recognize this peculiar website behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

I saw the link to this post in forwarded emails.

```
ErrorDocument 503 "Your connection was refused"
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "X11; Ubuntu; Linux" bad_user
Deny from env=bad_user
```

Was set in the .htaccess to block "WP-login bots", since I use Ubuntu myself this was rather easy to replicate.

Comment: I take it you were forwarded (parts of) my email to the website's builder? Do you happen to know where this rule came from? Is this an isolated case replicated only on websites provisioned by a single party (hopefully!), or is there some documentation out there in the wild that literally recommends this?

Fascinating in any case.

Comment: From what I have seen it was implemented on all .htaccess files on that server for all websites deployed 3 years ago. Probably a "brute force" measure against a random WP attack bot by an admin who did not think about the broader impact of such a measure.